# Why is apache not passing Location header from cgi script back to client

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection, cgi

I have an existing cgi web app which used to work fine, but whose behaviour has changed.

One of the cgi programs (under certain conditions) returns a Location header, to cause a redirect.

The Location header never reaches the web browser - instead, Apache seems to return the contents of the page the Location header redirects to.

Unfortunately that page contains javascript which uses the query string inside the Location header - but with this new behaviour the query string is empty, because the browser still thinks the location is the original cgi script.

Why has theis behaviour changed, and what can I do to prevent it happening?

Comment: [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390754/1025421), the key is whether an absolute URL is specified in the `Location` header.

Comment: Aha! I never knew that. If you make your comment into an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390754/1025421), CGI specifies two different types of redirects: internal and external.

*Internal redirects* (invisible to the browser) are used when you specify a URL without scheme and host (like `otherpage.html` or `/index.html`) in the `Location` header.

*External redirects* (performed by the browser) are used only when you specify an absolute URL (ie. `http://www.example.com/some/other/page`). Absolute URLs *must* start with the scheme (ie. `http`).

[RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#page-26) contains the relevant documentation:

> The Location header field is used to specify to the server that the
> script is returning a reference to a document rather than an actual
> document (see sections 6.2.3 and 6.2.4).  It is either an absolute
> URI (optionally with a fragment identifier), indicating that the
> client is to fetch the referenced document, or a local URI path
> (optionally with a query string), indicating that the server is to
> fetch the referenced document and return it to the client as the
> response.